# Find which django model field contains a bad value

Tags: python, django, debugging

I'm new to stackoverflow and to python\django. I have already solved my problem, but I hoped that I can get help about how to solve it faster next time.

I have a very simple python function which copies table records from one db to another (sql server to sqllite). The table has hundreds of columns. When I save the model object to sqllite, django throws the following exception:

'utf8' codec can't decode byte ...

I understand that the data in one of the columns is problematic for utf8 conversion. What I wanted to know is what columns this is. I tried different approaches but eventually I had to write the following code to find the bad column:

```
build = Builds.objects.using('realdb').get(buildid=12524)
n = Builds()
for field in Builds._meta.fields:
    val = getattr(build, field.name);
    try:
        setattr(n, field.name, val)
        n.save(using="default")
    except:
        return HttpResponse(field.name + ": " + val.__str__())
```

It basically copies column values one be one to the new model object and stops when it encounters an error. Is there a better way to do this next time? I tried breaking on exception in PyCharm, but it breaks on all the many of exceptions thrown within django framework itself.

Alon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way of determining which specific field is causing the problem without resorting to testing each and every field as you're doing here. You can try to repair the problem fields instead  of returning the error.

Take a look at [this section of the unicode docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type). Basically you can coerce the values by replacing the non-unicode portion or removing the non-unicode portion altogether.

Alternatively, if you know what encoding the strings are in, you can decode the string and re-encode appropriately using `string.encode` and `string.decode` respectively.